# How to obfuscate whole code even manifest file in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Am developing android application with some confidential data.I need to obfuscate code.I have searched for a solution long time, still am not getting solution.

Comment: If you want people to suggest solutions to a problem you should describe what you have tried, and in what way that failed to give you the results you wanted.

Comment: you can not obfuscate manifest file as it referencing the activities and permissions and all
get confidential information from server side make a webservice for that

Comment: Recardo already give a correct answer. But if you have confidential data in the app, it is basically maybe a design problem. You should not store confidential data inside the app.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways of doing this. The one you can easily integrate inside your application is to use proguard rules and gradle.

Define your proguard-rules.pro with the specifications you see fit. Below there is a link which explains the usage of most of them

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html

After that, in the build gradle of your top application module, in case you have a tree of dependencies, add:

```
BuildTypes{
    release{
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

In this case, every time you run a release version of your application, it will run your proguard file configuration. Have in consideration that proguard does not obfuscate the name of the activities.

Answer (score -1):

Use  `minifyEnabled true` in your app level build.gradle